# Structured Data Testing Tool: "There is an error in your Sitelinks Search Box template: OFF_DOMAIN"

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

I am trying to implement Schema.org markup (`WebSite` type):

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "WebSite",
        "url": "Page URL",
        "potentialAction": {
            "@type": "SearchAction",
            "target": "https://www.finelovedolls.com/fr/?s={search_term}&post_type=product",
            "query-input": "required name=search_term"
            }
    }
</script>
```

It seems correct as the `target` is what my website returns as a variable URL when using the search box.

However, I get the following mistake on Google SDTT results:

> URL Template: `https://www.finelovedolls.com/fr/?s={search_term}&post_type=product` (There is an error in your Sitelinks Search Box template: OFF_DOMAIN.)

Comment: How is this related to Google Tag Manager (which is a solution to implement marketing and tracking code into a website via a web interface) ? You might want to remove that tag (also the wordpress tag looks a little out of place).

Comment: Tag manager ? why ?

Comment: I use it to dynamically generate schema/JSON-LD tags

Answer (score 2):

Google’s Structured Data Testing Tool seems to check if the host from the `target` value is the same as the host from the `url` value.

So if you use `"url": "https://www.finelovedolls.com/fr/"` instead of `"url": "Page URL"`, the testing tool shouldn’t report this error anymore.

Comment: Hi Unor, thank you for your reply. I tagged the question in "Goggle Tag Manager" because I use it to dynamically inject variables into the JSON-LD. Sorry I forgot the brackets, it's: {{Page URL}} (built-in variable from GTM.)
So your suggestion won't work unfortunately as I still need to have this data to be rendered dynamically...!

Comment: Would that have something to do with Cloudflare...?

Comment: But you checked the markup in [Google’s SDTT](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?hl=en), right? I think it doesn’t execute any JavaScript, so you have to test your resulting HTML (with the correctly populated values) there, not your source (doesn’t matter if it uses GTM or any other way to populate the values).